# How to extract key-value pairs from valid JavaScript source code (not JSON) via regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing, multiline

**The string, though being perfectly valid JS source code, does not meet the JSON format. Therefore I don't think there's a simple solution which allows the usage of `JSON.parse`. Although i may be wrong.**

---

**Problem**

I have a string of key value pairs and would like extract them using regex.

- The keys are all known
- The separator is a colon
- The key may or may not be surrounded by single or double quotes. i.e `key:value`, `'key':value`, `"key":value`
- There may or may not be space between the key and the separator. i.e `key:value`, `key :value`
- There may or may not be space between the separator and the value. i.e `key:value`, `key: value`
- The value may or may not be surrounded by single or double quotes. i.e `key:value`, `key:"value"`, `key:'value'`
- The value may consist of multiline text. i.e

```js
key: {
       val1: 1,
       val2: 2,
       val3: 3,
     }
```

```js
key: [
       val1,
       val2,
       val3,
     ]
```

```js
key: (arg1, arg2) => {
       return {
         arg1,
         arg2
       }
     }
```

**Example**

The string:

```
value1         :        true,
value2 : "something, something-else",
value3: [
  {
    a: 'a',
    b: true,
    c: 3
  }, {
    a: Thing,
    func: () => {
      return new Thing()
    }
  }
],
"value4": [1, 2, 3, 4],
'value5': "['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']",
value6: false
```

Ultimately i'd like to end up with a 2 dimensional array containing the key value pairs, but can handle that once the keys and values have been extracted using the regex.

The desired result:

```
 [
   ['value1', true],
   ['value2', 'something, something-else'],
   ['value3', "{
                 a: 'a',
                 b: true,
                 c: 3
               }, {
                 a: Thing,
                 func: () => {
                   return new Thing()
                 }
               }"],
   ['value4', "[1, 2, 3, 4]"],
   ['value5', "['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']"],
   ['value6', false]
 [
```

**Attempted solution**

This is what i've come up with so far:

```
(?<key>value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6)["'\s]*?:\s*(?<value>(?!value1|value2|value3|value4|value5).*)
```

1. Use a named capture group to explicitly match the key to the left of the colon - taking into account the optional single or double quotes and whitespace either side

```
(?<key>value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6)["'\s]*?:
```

2. Use a negative lookahead to match the value up to the next key

```
\s*(?<value>(?!value1|value2|value3|value4|value5).*)
```

But this doesn't appear to be doing what i thought it was, as if you remove all the words and replace them with something arbitrary, the result is still the same

```
\s*(?<value>(?!a).*)
```

I realise that this isn't actually checking for a newline, but i'm not sure how to incorporate that?

Attempted solution on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xhlGjd/2)

**Nice to have**

For the value, only extract what's inside the optional single of double quotes, not the quotes or comma. i.e this `something, something-else` rather than `'something, something-else',`

**Note**

The regex101 example is set to PCRE so that i can use the Regex debugger, but i'm looking for a solution that uses valid javascript regex.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a regex like ...

```js
/^(?:(?<quote>['"])(?<dequotedKey>[^'"]+)\k<quote>|(?<unquotedKey>\w+))\s*\:\s*(?<value>.*?),*$/
```

... where its global multiline variant produces [matches like shown at this regex playground](https://regex101.com/r/DtrZWT/1), one would chose a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach which does process line based tokens that are the result of [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)ting the source string at each newline.

The implementation then is very straightforward. For each line-token one just does execute the regex and tries accessing the regex-result's [named capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups). As soon as at least the `value` capture does exist one has a valid match, thus, one can push a valid key-value pair into the OP's result array where the key either is unquoted or was captured as its dequoted variant. In case `value` is null, nothing did match which indicates a multiline value of the last collected valid key-value pair. Thus one has to line-wise concatenate the value of the latter.

```js
const regXKeyValueCaptures =
  /^(?:(?<quote>['"])(?<dequotedKey>[^'"]+)\k<quote>|(?<unquotedKey>\w+))\s*\:\s*(?<value>.*?),*$/;

console.log(

  sampleData
    .split(/\n/)
    .reduce((result, lineToken) => {
      const {
        dequotedKey = null,
        unquotedKey = null,
        value = null,
      } = regXKeyValueCaptures.exec(lineToken)?.groups ?? {};

      if (value === null) {
        result.at(-1)[1] = `${ result.at(-1)[1] }\n${ lineToken }`;
      } else {
        result.push([dequotedKey || unquotedKey, value]);
      }
      return result;
    }, [])

);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
const sampleData =
`value1         :        true,
value2 : "something, something-else",
value3: [
  {
    a: 'a',
    b: true,
    c: 3
  }, {
    a: Thing,
    func: () => {
      return new Thing()
    }
  }
],
"value4": [1, 2, 3, 4],
'value5': "['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']",
value6: false`;
</script>
```

In case the OP is in need of the question's requested result which does not equal the above implementation's parsed raw result, the above code then needs to be accompanied by an additional sanitizing tasks which does strip trailing and leading quotes from each key-value pair's value.

```js
const regXKeyValueCaptures =
  /^(?:(?<quote>['"])(?<dequotedKey>[^'"]+)\k<quote>|(?<unquotedKey>\w+))\s*\:\s*(?<value>.*?),*$/;

console.log(

  sampleData
    .split(/\n/)
    .reduce((result, lineToken) => {
      const {
        dequotedKey = null,
        unquotedKey = null,
        value = null,
      } = regXKeyValueCaptures.exec(lineToken)?.groups ?? {};

      if (value === null) {
        result.at(-1)[1] = `${ result.at(-1)[1] }\n${ lineToken }`;
      } else {
        result.push([dequotedKey || unquotedKey, value]);
      }
      return result;

    }, []).map(([key, value]) =>

      [key, value.replace(/^["']|["']$/g, '')]
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
const sampleData =
`value1         :        true,
value2 : "something, something-else",
value3: [
  {
    a: 'a',
    b: true,
    c: 3
  }, {
    a: Thing,
    func: () => {
      return new Thing()
    }
  }
],
"value4": [1, 2, 3, 4],
'value5': "['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']",
value6: false`;
</script>
```

**EDIT**

***Bonus ... entirely "regex and capturing groups only" based approach***

Having dealt a lot with the first regex pattern, I thought it couldn't be that difficult to find a **regex only** approach. So after trying a little and giving the before ...

```js
/^(?:(?<quote>['"])(?<dequotedKey>[^'"]+)\k<quote>|(?<unquotedKey>\w+))\s*\:\s*(?<value>.*?),*$/
```

... a twist, the regex which can deal with the parsing just by itself is ...

```js
/(?:^|\n)(?:(?<quote>['"])(?<dequotedKey>[^'"]+)\k<quote>|(?<unquotedKey>\w+))\s*\:\s*(?<value>.*?)(?=,\n['"\w]|$)/gs
```

Its [explanation and how it actually works can be found a this regex' playground](https://regex101.com/r/DtrZWT/2).

The main changes are ...

- the treatment of the multiline string as **s**ingle line, hence the [single line flag](https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction#flags), which allows the `value` group to capture multiline matches via the non greedy dot all (`.*?`) quantifier,
- and the combination of a [non capturing group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Non-capturing_group)ed [alternation](https://javascript.info/regexp-alternation) `(?:^|\n)` at the pattern's beginning and the [positive lookahead](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookahead) (with an alternation too `(?=,\n['"\w]|$)`) at the end of the pattern which both do identify the beginning and the end of a key-value pair even if it is spread over several newlines.

Utilizing the new pattern and adapting the before introduced code accordingly leads to following implementation ...

```js
const regXKeyValueCaptures =
  /(?:^|\n)(?:(?<quote>['"])(?<dequotedKey>[^'"]+)\k<quote>|(?<unquotedKey>\w+))\s*\:\s*(?<value>.*?)(?=,\n['"\w]|$)/gs;

console.log(

  [...sampleData.matchAll(regXKeyValueCaptures)]
    .map(({ groups: { dequotedKey, unquotedKey, value } }) => [

      (dequotedKey || unquotedKey),
      value.replace(/^["']|["']$/g, ''),
    ])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
const sampleData =
`value1         :        true,
value2 : "something, something-else",
value3: [
  {
    a: 'a',
    b: true,
    c: 3
  }, {
    a: Thing,
    func: () => {
      return new Thing()
    }
  }
],
"value4": [1, 2, 3, 4],
'value5': "['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']",
value6: false`;
</script>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for the thorough explanation. I also wasn't aware of `\k<groupName>` to access previously captured values. Looks like regex101.com might be offline at the moment, i'll check it out later to get a better understanding of what `regXKeyValueCaptures` is actually doing

Comment: @james ... There is a late 3rd implementation. I was able to figure out an entirely _**"regex and capturing groups only"**_ based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Is the order of the keys known? If so, you could try to slice the source string from one key to the next, and then removing the unwanted bits (spaces, line breaks, commas, quotes) from the start and end of each individual value:

```js
const str = `
  value1         :        true,
  value2 : "something, something-else",
  value3: [
    {
      a: 'a',
      b: true,
      c: 3
    }, {
      a: Thing,
      func: () => {
        return new Thing()
      }
    }
  ],
  "value4": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'value5': "['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']",
  value6: false
`

function clean(dirtyValue) {
  return dirtyValue
    .replace(/^['"]?\s*\:\s*/, '')
    .replace(/,?\s*['"]?$/, '')
}

const keys = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6']

const parsed = keys.reduce((acc, key, i) => {
  const indexOfKey = str.indexOf(key);
  const indexOfNextKey = i < keys.length - 1 ? str.indexOf(keys[i + 1]) : str.length
  
  acc[key] = clean(str.slice(indexOfKey + key.length, indexOfNextKey))

  return acc;
}, {})

Object.entries(parsed).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(key, '=', value))
```

You can also adapt the example above to work with unsorted keys:

```js
const str = `
  value1         :        true,
  value2 : "something, something-else",
  value3: [
    {
      a: 'a',
      b: true,
      c: 3
    }, {
      a: Thing,
      func: () => {
        return new Thing()
      }
    }
  ],
  "value4": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'value5': "['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']",
  value6: false
`

function clean(dirtyValue) {
  return dirtyValue
    .replace(/^['"]?\s*\:\s*/, '')
    .replace(/,?\s*['"]?$/, '')
}

function shuffleArray(arr) {
  const shuffledArray = arr.slice(0)

  for (let i = shuffledArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));    

      [shuffledArray[i], shuffledArray[j]] = [shuffledArray[j], shuffledArray[i]]
  }

  return shuffledArray;
}

const keys = shuffleArray(['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6'])

const parsed = keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
  const indexOfKey = str.indexOf(key);
      
  const closestIndexOfNextKey = keys.map((possibleNextKey) => {
    const possibleNextKeyIndex = str.indexOf(possibleNextKey, indexOfKey + 1)
    
    return possibleNextKeyIndex <= 0 ? Infinity : possibleNextKeyIndex
  }).sort((a, b) => a - b)[0]
  
  acc[key] = clean(str.slice(indexOfKey + key.length, closestIndexOfNextKey))

  return acc;
}, {})

Object.entries(parsed).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(key, '=', value))
```

Note if you have many keys, you might want to optimize this code by removing the keys you already found from the keys array.

Comment: Thanks. Randomly i was just wondering the same thing. About slicing or even splitting on the keys at least. But no, they can be in any order unfortunately, i have no control over that

Comment: That has given me an idea though, as i know the keys i could search and replace the keys first with something that would allow me to then split them on the keys, if that makes sense. Like adding something to the beginning of each key and then spitting on that

Comment: @james You can do that, or just find what's the next key. I've added another version of the script that works with unsorted keys.

Comment: @james  Be aware that any keys inside the values will then cause you issues.  eg.  In the above snippets try changing value2 to  -> `value2 : "something, something-else, value3",`   But if you can be sure that none of the values will contain any of the keys, it could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem with the following regex (which can probably be optimised, but does the job i needed it to do):

```
/(?<key>value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6)["' ]*?:[ '"]*(?<value>[\s\S]*?)(?:[ '",]*?\n*?[ '",]*?)(?=value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6|$)/g
```

It captures the key to the left of the colon in the named group 'key' and allows for optional whitespace or single/double quotes after the key:

```
(?<key>value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6)["' ]*?:
```

It then matches the value on the right of the colon using a negative lookahead to find either the next key or the end of the string. Preceding the negative lookahead it looks for:

- An optional mixture of a spaces, single/double quotes and a comma
- The value (captured by the named group 'value')
- An optional newline
- An optional mixture of a spaces, single/double quotes and a comma

```
[ '"]*(?<value>[\s\S]*?)(?:[ '",]*?\n*?[ '",]*?)(?=value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6|$)
```

Working demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/HMAHEe/1)

---

```js
const str = `value1         :        true,
  value2 : 'something, something-else',
  value3: [
    {
      a: 'a',
      b: true,
      c: 3
    }, {
      a: Thing,
      func: () => {
        return new Thing()
      }
    }
  ],
  "value4": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'value5': "['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']",
  value6: false`;

  const keyAndValue = new RegExp(/(?<key>value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6)["' ]*?:[ '"]*(?<value>[\s\S]*?)(?:[ '",]*?\n*?[ '",]*?)(?=value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6|$)/, 'g');

  console.log([...str.matchAll(keyAndValue)])
```

Comment: Not me who down-voted, but it might be because your output was not the same as you showed.  But you could fix that with just -> `console.log([...str.matchAll(keyAndValue)].map(x=>x.slice(1)))` .  Also remember, like the other poster using regex, this can break very easily, eg. having say any of your `key:` anywhere else in the source could cause issues.  But you know your data, so that should be fine.  Personally I'm not bothered about rep score, as you might have seen I practically encouraged jabba to downvote me, rather that than him trying to police SO.  ps: I'll upvote to counter :)

Answer (score -1):

The Data your getting is not JSON, but looks like it's a Javascript Object instead, with the starting `{` and end `}` taken off.

As such you could just parse this using `eval`, but be aware of issues of `eval`, IOW: make sure you trust the source.

Your source has some functions like `Thing()` so would need stubbing, below I've used a little hack to trap the exceptions and add `Thing` automatically, it works on here for me on Chrome & Firefox, but parsing an error string just feels a little hacky, so just something to be aware off.

I've noticed your result for boolean's is not wrapping in strings, so I've done a test for that, because I've just used JSON to do the value part it's not exactly the same as your output, but that could be replaced with a custom one that that gets closer to what your after.

Anything more detailed than that, I would suggest using an AST to parse it, it might be possible with `regex`, but I feel like they could be some edge cases that will catch you out.   If you do use an AST, don't forget to add the `{` & `}` to make so it can parse.

```js
const src = `value1         :        true,
value2 : "something, something-else",
value3: [
  {
    a: 'a',
    b: true,
    c: 3
  }, {
    a: Thing,
    func: () => {
      return new Thing()
    }
  }
],
"value4": [1, 2, 3, 4],
'value5': "['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']",
value6: false`;

function keyValue(src) {
  const stubs = [];
  for (let l = 0; l < 100; l ++) {
    try {
      const stubsTxt = stubs.map(m=>`function ${m}(){}`).join(';');
      const p = eval(`${stubsTxt};({${src}})`);
      return Object.entries(p).map(([k, v]) => {
        return [k, typeof v === 'boolean' ? v : JSON.stringify(v)]
      });
    } catch (e) {
      const t = e.toString().split(' ');
      if (t[0] === 'ReferenceError:') {
        stubs.push(t[1]);
      } else break;
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('pre').innerText = JSON.stringify(keyValue(src), null, '  ');
```

```html
<pre>
</pre>
```

Comment: It's not what i'm looking for, but thanks for taking the time to try and find a solution to my problem